# How to change the close icon (x) on tab to circle in vscode extension webview tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

As I see when we edit a text file in vscode, the close icon (x) will change to a circle to indicate that the tab/file is edited (dirty) so user can Ctrl S to save.

I followed this [tut](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) to create a webview tab with some html input. When user edit some fields on this webview, I want to change the close icon as in the case of text file. How can we do that?